# Numpy Broken "For" Loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy

I have been working on a Numpy script and it has suddenly started acting up. 
I wrote the For loop line at the beginning, and have tested the script about 20 or so times with no trouble. Now that I think other issues are resolved, Python is telling me that the "for" syntax is wrong. Does anybody have any ideas? 
The exact Python output is:

```
File "Test.py", line 17
    for t in range(10):
      ^
```

Script code is:

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3

import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

tau = 10

c = sp.recfromtxt("test.txt")
binsmax = np.max(c)

f, dummy = np.histogram(c, bins=(np.arange(binsmax+1))

for t in range(tau):

    if t==0:
        a = c[:len(c)-1]
    else:
        a = c[:-(t+1)]

    d = c[1:]
    b = d
    c = a + b
    newmax = np.max(c)

    if binsmax < newmax:
        binsmax = newmax

    hist, dummy2 = np.histogram(c, bins=[np.arange(binsmax+1)])

    if binsmax < newmax:
        difference = newmax - binsmax
        np.append(f, np.zeros(difference)) 
    else:
        difference = binsmax - newmax
        np.append(hist, np.zeros(difference))
    e = f
    f = hist + e                   # 'f' is the running histogram

    sp.savetxt(str(t)+"c.txt", c)
    sp.savetxt(str(t)+"f.txt", f)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're short a close parens in this line:

```
f, dummy = np.histogram(c, bins=(np.arange(binsmax+1))
```

Comment: Crazy fast response, and absolutely correct. Thanks! For loop is fixed. Now I can get back to the rest of the crap. :)

Comment: You'll get better at finding those. For many programming languages and compilers, it pays to check the line above the error.